# Add pre-defined custom fields in Wordpress without plugin

Tags: wordpress

With new possibilities of WP3+, custom taxonomies, custom post types, is there a way to create, without the use of a plugin a custom field with or without predefined values to choose from ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please explain this in more detail. Or give a real example of what you want the outcome to be.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to look at custom meta boxes....

You can completely control extra data for specific posts in their own separate box.

Codex link:

[add_meta_box - Docs - WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box)

You will need to hook in to the 'save_post' action hook to save your custom data.